# JS to popup my webpage in a third-party site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, popup, lightbox

I need to popup my webpage from within our customer's websites. My webpage gathers some data in input boxes and then closes --- ie. It's just a basic form and all I need is to display it and give a close button to the user.

What's the best JS tool to do this? I found colorbox and it looks cool, but I am concerned that it will break my customer's site as it requires jQuery (and my customer may be using an older version than colorbox pulls in).

Comment: what is the version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: The problem is not the jQuery version. The issue is that I have 1000+ customers and this popup needs to be launched from within my customers' sites. So the customers would be using an assortment of programming languages, javascript tools etc., and all I want is to give them a single line of HTML "that will just work"...

Comment: If your single line of HTML starts with <iframe>, no problem!

Comment: I prefer a nice toolkit that I can reuse... Avoids me having to debugging browser specific issues, gives me a nice popup layout, fades background etc.

Comment: I recently wrote something specific to this. Its on GitHub at https://github.com/akshayrawat/js_iframe_modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that you will struggle to achieve this given the cross-site scripting prevention mechanisms in browsers.

You cannot load a page using ajax from another domain for example.

You can certainly load the page using a "workaround", which uses javascript to load content from an external url by document.writing a javascript script tag with the url of your page, this mimics an http get. (example here [xss](http://spotthevuln.com/2010/06/every-crosssitescripting/))

You would not be able to post the resulting form back to your site, but with some javascript you could read the form data and create another get request by building up the querystring of the url.

**EDIT**

```
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" src="mysite.com/page"/>
```

...

```
function show()
{
  document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display = "block";
}

function hide()
{
  document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I think I phrased it incorrectly. I am really just looking to display my page at http://myCompany.com within an iframe, and make it collect some form info. Then the user closes the iframe and end of story. There is to be no 'sharing' of data with the parent page, in which case there will be no domain issues?

Comment: then you can use javascript to create an iframe element on the fly and append it to another element, or have it load in the page with a css style of display:hidden - when u wish to display it change this style to display:block and back again to hide it...have edited my post for some pointers